# Can you get the pre-order weapons within the game without a pre-order?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Are the bonus weapons that were gotten through pre-order for Dark Souls 2 only available through pre-order or can you find them within the game as drops as well?

Comment: I can't promise it, but I'm quite sure they can be found in the game as well. My card with the code in it says it gives "early access to the Black Armour weapon set", so it probably just gives you the weapons right in the beginning to make the start easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collector's edition only gives early access to the weapons. [This article](http://www.forbes.com/sites/erikkain/2014/02/12/why-the-dark-souls-ii-black-armor-weapons-set-is-a-terrible-idea/) talks about it and reveal where you can find those weapons with the "normal" edition.